# db.dropUser("user") returning false when logged in as root

Tags: mongodb

I am logged in with the following:

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.root",
    "user" : "root",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following happens:

```
> use mydb
switched to db mydb
> db.dropUser("mydbReadWrite")
false
```

I suspect I do not have the roles, I am root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was correct, the user was somehow dropped before without notifying me(hmm...). So it returned false as the user did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

may be you need switch to the db that you create the uesr "mydbReadWrite"